# Dispatch queues, concurrency and completion handling

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, objective-c-blocks, grand-central-dispatch

I have an array of objects to be processed. The objects have a method like below

```
@interface CustomObject : NSObject

- (void)processWithCompletionBlock:(void (^)(BOOL success))completionBlock;

@end
```

The processing of each object takes various time and can have different results. And it is known that the processing itself is executing concurrently. To say the truth it would be great to limit the number of concurrent operations because they are pretty intensive.

So I need to enumerate this array of objects and process them. If some object processing fails I need to skip all the rest objects. And of course I need to be notified after all objects will be enumerated and processed.

Should it be solved by the creation of `NSOperationQueue` and `NSOperation` subclass? How this class could look to fulfill these requirements? Are there some other elegant approaches?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok. To help others to understand how this approach can be handled I am sharing my own code.

To limit the number of concurrent threads we can call the `-(void)setMaximimumConcurrentOperationCount:` method of `NSOperationQueue` instance.

To iterate objects and provide the completion mechanism we can define the following method:

```
- (void)enumerateObjects:(NSArray *)objects
{
    // define the completion block
    NSBlockOperation *completionOperation = [NSBlockOperation blockOperationWithBlock:^{
        NSLog(@"Update UI");
    }];

    // register dependencies
    for (CustomObject *obj in objects) {
        CustomOperation *operation = [[CustomOperation alloc] initWithCustomObject:obj];
        [completionOperation addDependency:operation]; // set dependencies for the completion block
        [_operationQueue addOperation:operation];
    }

    // register completionOperation on main queue to avoid the cancellation
    [[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] addOperation:completionOperation];
}
```

Overwrite the `- (void)start` method of the `NSOperation` subclass to start our custom operation:

```
- (void)start
{
    // We need access to the operation queue for canceling other operations if the process fails
    _operationQueue = [NSOperationQueue currentQueue];

    if ([self isCancelled]) {
        // Must move the operation to the finished state if it is canceled.
        [self willChangeValueForKey:@"isFinished"];
        _finished = YES;
        [self didChangeValueForKey:@"isFinished"];
        return;
    }

    [self willChangeValueForKey:@"isExecuting"];
    // We do not need thread detaching because our `-(void)processWithCompletionBlock:` method already uses dispatch_async
    [self main]; // [NSThread detachNewThreadSelector:@selector(main) toTarget:self withObject:nil];
    _executing = YES;
    [self didChangeValueForKey:@"isExecuting"];

}
```

Overwrite the `- (void)main` method of the `NSOperation` subclass to process our custom object:

```
- (void)main
{
    @try {
        NSLog(@"Processing object %@", _customObject);
        [_customObject processWithCompletionBlock:^(BOOL success) {
            _processed = success;
            if (!success) {
                NSLog(@"Cancelling other operations");
                [_operationQueue cancelAllOperations];
            }
            [self completeOperation];
        }];
    }

    @catch (NSException *exception) {
        NSLog(@"Exception raised, %@", exception);
    }
}
```

Thanx to @Rob for pointing me out to the missing part.

Answer (score 1):

This is exactly what `NSOperation` is designed for. Dispatch queues are much lower-level handlers, and you'd have to construct many of the pieces you need for this. You can of course do that (`NSOperationQueue` is built on top of GCD), but you'd be reinventing `NSOperation`.

You can handle `NSOperation` two ways for the most part. If it's simple, you can just create an `NSBlockOperation`. If it's a bit more complex, you can subclass `NSOperation` and override the `main` method to do what you want.

There are several ways to cancel all the other operations. You could have a separate operation queue per group. Then you can easily call `cancelAllOperations` to shut down everything. Or you could have a separate controller that knows the list of related operations and it could call `cancel` on them.

Remember that "cancel" just means "don't schedule if it hasn't stared, and set `isCancelled` if it has." It doesn't abort a running operation. If you want to abort a running operation, the operation needs to periodically check `isCancelled`.

You typically should limit the number of concurrent operations the queue will run. Use `setMaximimumConcurrentOperationCount:`.

There are two ways to determine that all the operations are finished. You can make an extra operation (usually a `BlockOperation`) and use `addDependency:` to make it depend on all the other operations. That's a nice asynchronous solution. If you can handle a synchronous solution, then you can use `waitUntilAllOperationsAreFinished`. I typically prefer the former.

Comment: How this class could look to fulfill these requirements?

Comment: Rob Napier, how do you use addDependency on BlockOperations?

Comment: An `NSBlockOperation` ISA `NSOperation`, and you can call `addDependency:` on `NSOperation`. I'm not sure what else you mean.

Answer (score 1):

Use NSOperationQueue and make your Class an NSOperation

Use this method to queue your work

```
- (void)addOperations:(NSArray *)ops waitUntilFinished:(BOOL)wait
```

Add a reference to the operation queue to the NSOperation subclass you create

If an error occurs call

```
- (void)setSuspended:(BOOL)suspend
```

on NSOperationQueue

Comment: Did you mean `-(void)setCancelled`? :)

Comment: There is no setCancelled on NSOperationQueue, or NSOperation there is a cancelAllOperations though which would work fine.

Comment: How this class could look to fulfill these requirements?

Comment: I dunno I guess someone should write it, Im not doing peoples comp sci homework here.